# Не удаляется животное из customer

Tags: java, java-ee

При регистрации клиента можно создать несколько животных, которые будут ему принадлежат, добавить животных получается, но удалить нет.

При попытке удалить животное Pet из Customer, пишет что их нет, но они были добавлены.

Ошибка:

> Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException     at
>   com.eventim.petshop.entities.PetRepository.deletePet(PetRepository.java:20)
>     at
>   java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native
>   Method)   at
>   java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)

Код:

```
@Stateful
public class PetRepository extends AbstractRepository {

    private Pet pet;
    Customer customer;

    public Pet createPet(String name) {
        Pet pet = new Pet();
        pet.setName(name);
        entityManager.persist(pet);
        return pet;
    }

    public void deletePet(String name) {
       for (Pet pets : customer.getPets() ){ // видимо здесь не находит
           if (pets.getName().equals(name))
               entityManager.remove(pets.getName());
       }

    }

}
```

Клиент:

```
    @NamedQuery(name ="CUSTOMER.findByLogin", query = "SELECT c FROM CUSTOMER c WHERE c.login = ?1")
    @Entity(name = "CUSTOMER")
    public class Customer {

        //public static final String FIND_BY_USERNAME_AND_PASSWORD = "findByUsernameAndPassword";
        public static final String FIND_BY_USERNAME = "SELECT c FROM CUSTOMER c WHERE c.login = ?1";


        @Id
        @GeneratedValue
        private Integer id;

        @Column(unique = true)
        private String login;

        @Column
        private String password;

        @OneToMany
        private List<Pet> pets = new ArrayList<>();

      get и set ---

public Collection<Pet> getPets() { return pets; }

        public void setPets(List<Pet> pets) {
            this.pets = pets;
        }


      /*  public List<Customer> getAllCustomer(){
            Query query;
            return query.getResultList();
        }*/


        public boolean isPetExist(String name){
            for (Pet pet: getPets()){
                if (pet.getName().equals(name)){
                    return true;
                }
            }
            return false;
        }

    }
```

Maneger:

```
@Stateful
public class PetManager {

    @EJB
    private PetRepository petRepository;

    @EJB
    private CustomerRepository customerRepository;

    public void createPet(Integer customerId, String name) {
        if (!customerRepository.findCostumerById(customerId).isPetExist(name)){
        Pet pet = petRepository.createPet(name);
        customerRepository.addPetToCustomer(customerId, pet);}
        else {
            FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, new FacesMessage("Pets already exits"));
        }
    }

    public void deletePet(Integer customerId, String name) {
        if (customerRepository.findCostumerById(customerId).isPetExist(name)){
            petRepository.deletePet(name); }
        else {
            FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, new FacesMessage("Pets not exits"));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Метод getPets() отсутствует.

Comment: public Collection<Pet> getPets() {
        return pets;
    }  я его здесь не написал чтобы код меньше был, полцчается, что customer  в методе deletePet всегда null

Comment: Так return this.pets, не?

Comment: попроовал,нет изменений

Comment: А в каком месте животные добавляются? Где класс main?

Comment: Они добавляются в БД, main класса нет

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
  public void deletePet(Integer customerId, String name) {
        if (customerRepository.findCostumerById(customerId).isPetExist(name)){

            Collection<Pet> temp =  customerRepository.findCostumerById(customerId).getPets();
            Optional<Pet> pet =  temp.stream().filter(p->p.getName().equals(name)).findFirst();
            if (pet.isPresent()) petRepository.deletePet(pet.get());

                FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, new FacesMessage("Pets deleted")); }
        else {
            FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, new FacesMessage("Pets not exits"));
        }
    }
```